# Enumeration in C#

Tags: c#, .net, enums, foreach, enumeration

I am trying to enumerate the runtime input to print values of enum variable in c#.
For example,

```
class Program
{
   enum Alphabets { a = 1, b, c, d, e, f, g, h }

   public static void Main(String[] args)
   {
       string s = Console.ReadLine();

       foreach(char c in s)
       {
           foreach(int i in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Alphabets)))
              Console.WriteLine(s[i]);
       }

       Console.ReadKey();
   }
}
```

I stored the user input in String s. I need to display the integer values of the string provided by the user. 
The above code show some error like the following:
[image: Index error!] 
How can i correct this? or provide me a efficient code please..

Comment: Your code would be *much* easier to read if you would indent it. It would also be helpful if you would give sample input and output.

Comment: @Jon Skeet if try try your code it says error in c.ReadLine(); as char does not contain a definition for 'Read'

Comment: That would have been a better comment *on my answer* - however, I've edited it now anyway, as Alexei had pointed it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I *think* you want something along these lines:

```
string line = Console.ReadLine();
foreach (char c in line)
{
    string name = c.ToString();
    Alphabets parsed = (Alphabets) Enum.Parse(typeof(Alphabets), name);
    Console.WriteLine((int) parsed);
}
```

So this converts each character into a string, and tries to parse it as a member of `Alphabets`. Each parsed value is then converted into an `int` just by casting.

Answer (score 0):

check this code. This is enough

```
 enum Alphabets { a = 1, b, c, d, e, f, g, h , i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z }

        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            string s = Console.ReadLine();

            foreach (char c in s)
            {
                Alphabets parsed = (Alphabets)Enum.Parse(typeof(Alphabets), c.ToString());
                 Console.WriteLine((int)parsed);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```